# Solo mining on geth: Libcurl error 7

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, json-rpc

Trying to setup solo mining using Geth, but every time I try to start mining I get:

```
X Failed to submit hashrate.
X Dynamic exception type: class jsonprc::JsonRpcException
std::exception::what: Exception -32003 : Client connector error: libcurl error:
7 -> Could not connect to http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

My blockchain is synchronized. What else could it be?

Comment: What's your command to run `geth`?

Comment: for ethos just run restart-proxy and the miner should connect

Comment: Bokky. Thank you. I registered here to say thanks as I could not find this solution anywhere else (web, YouTube etc.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19221)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using `geth` to run your Ethereum node, and `ethminer` to run the mining calculations. And you are running both from the same computer. If this is the case, here are some of the configuration parameters you will need to use:

`geth` will need to have the `--rpc` command line option:

```
geth --rpc --rpcaddr "127.0.0.1" --rpcport "8545" [your additional options]
```

It is mainly the `--rpc` option that you need above, as the `--rpcaddr` and `--rpcport` options are the default.

In `ethminer`, you will need the following configuration parameters:

```
ethminer -F http://127.0.0.1:8545 [your additional options]
```